# Reference cell not showing values in 1 decimal or 2 decimal places

Tags: excel

I'm taking a reference from a `cell M7` which has a value `30.0`

the `cell B2` has a reference to `cell M7` as  `=M7 & " mtr."`

The result displays as **30 mtr.**, but what I want is to show it as **30.00 mtr.** or **30.0 mtr.**

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

...but you can use the `TEXT` function, like:

```
=TEXT(M7,"0.00") & " mtr."
```

See [**this link**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) for more about the function.  [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is probably a better place for questions about how to use Excel.

Comment: I know it was not the programming question but I was wondering it for some time and you provided me the solution,  Thank you so much. Regards,

Comment: @ashleedawg  that debate was settled years ago, Excel Formula Q's _are_ a form of programming and _are_ on topic (other quality issues on withstanding).  If you want to reopen that debate, please take it to Meta